# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error de Integrity constraint violation: 1062 en laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Tengo un problema al crear un usuario con rol "administrador" para un sistema en laravel, sencillamente cuando le doy Crear a un nuevo usuario, me sale el error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> 'test@gmail.com' for key 'users.users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into
> `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `role`, `updated_at`,
> `created_at`) values (test, test@gmail.com,
> $2y$10$yPcaBsQJSPI20FiwmcJZXurPFqCRZu0OWX0uBsvah9T0jyPWPQdBS, Admin,
> 2023-02-25 00:05:41, 2023-02-25 00:05:41))

Dice que el email esta duplicado porque es unico pero eso no es posible porque no hay correos registrados, pero lo más raro de todo es que cuando le doy crear, me sale el error pero se registra en la base de datos.

este es la tabla "Users"

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('role');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Este es el UserRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
           
                'name' => ['required|min:3|alpha'],
                'email'=> ['required|email|unique:users,email|string', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($users->id) ],
                'password' => ['required|string|min:8|max:15'],
                'role'=> ['required']
            
        ];
    }
```

Este el UserController

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

       User::create(
           $request->only('name','email', 'password', 'role')
       );

         $usuarios = new User();
         $usuarios->name = $request->input('name');
         $usuarios->email = $request->input('email');
         $usuarios->password = $request->input('password');
         $usuarios->role = $request->input('role');
         $usuarios->save();

         return redirect('/usuarios');
    }
```

Comment: Parece que en el controlador tú mismo estás registrando al usuario dos veces. Observa los ejemplos de la [documenatación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts) y leela con cuidado

Comment: Convendría verificar que un registro no está duplicado antes de intentar insertarlo, para ello puedes crear un método que verifique eso con una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) laTabla WHERE columnaUnica=elValorNuevo`. Particularmente me gusta esta práctica, porque si la `columnaUnica` es del tipo autoincremental en la tabla, ese número crece a cada intento fallido. Imaginemos código de inserción masiva donde el código puede fallar `N` veces, el número secuencial de `columnaUnica` va a tener saltos considerables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estas creando dos veces al usuario en la base de datos. La primera vez, como tu mencionas, lo crea correctamente en la base de datos, pero la segunda vez da error porque ya existe el usuario:

Tienes que quitar una de los dos siguientes códigos. O este:

```
User::create(
    $request->only('name', 'email', 'password', 'role')
);
```

o este:

```
$usuarios = new User();
$usuarios->name = $request->input('name');
$usuarios->email = $request->input('email');
$usuarios->password = $request->input('password');
$usuarios->role = $request->input('role');
$usuarios->save();
```

pero los dos al mismo tiempo no puedes usarlos, ya que hacen exactamente lo mismo.

Con este cambio ya te funcionaría el código, pero existe otro error en el código:

Aunque exite el `UserRequest`, no lo estas usando. Tienes que cambiar `Request $request`  por `UserRequest $request`:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    User::create(
```

Saludos.